# Splitting RGB raw file into 3 files, one for each channel?

Tags: command-line, graphics

I need to convert an RGB raw file into 3 files containing each the red, green and blue channel.

Comment: How does the RGB data organized? `RGB RGB RGB` or `RRR GGG BBB`?

Comment: Just to be clear, this is a simple binary file, not digital camera output in so-called "RAW" format, right?

Comment: This is exactly a binary file containing only rgb data, no header information. file is organized as RGB RGB RGB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the netpbm tools? This will work with R8G8B8 and other 8-bit RGB orders.

For a width 100 height 200 RGB order raw file:

```
rawtoppm -rgb 100 200 input.rgb > image.ppm
ppmtorgb3 image.ppm
```

You will now have 3 `pgm` format grey-map files, each suffixed `.red` `.grn` and `.blu`. These `.pgm` files are *almost* a raw binary format, except for the short header, so:

```
tail +4 image.red > image_r.raw
tail +4 image.grn > image_g.raw
tail +4 image.blu > image_b.raw
```

if you really want the raw channels like that. Or, for further processing:

```
pgmtoppm red   image.red > image_red.ppm
pgmtoppm green image.grn > image_grn.ppm 
pgmtoppm blue  image.blu > image_blue.ppm
```

You now have three `ppm`format files which are the separated RGB channels (see also `rgb3toppm`). These can be convert to other formats using `ppmtoX`, e.g. `ppmtopng`.
Use "`white`" instead of the colour in the 2nd parameter to leave each as a grey scale.

Imagemagick's `convert` may also be also useful, it will handle RGB, RGBA and 16-bit raw formats too, and it has a `-separate` option to split channels.

```
for ch in R G B; do
  convert -set colorspace RGB -size 100x200 -depth 8 rgb:image.rgb \
      -channel ${ch} -separate -depth 8 gray:image_${ch}.raw
done
```

Check that the `-set colorspace` option is appropriate for your input.
Newer versions let you do this in a single command, see http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics

```
convert ... -channel RGB -separate gray:image_%d.raw
```

and R/G/B will be written to `image_0.raw image_1.raw image_2.raw` files

---

Note, `convert` command was updated based on help and feedback from *Stephane Chazelas*, there were several changes to colorspace behaviour from ImageMagic-6.7.7 which cause problems due to (I believe) sRGB being used instead of RGB.

```
  # colorspace changes mean this works differently after ImageMagick-6.7.6
  convert -size 100x200 -depth 8 rgb:image.rgb \
      -channel ${ch} -separate -depth 8 gray:image_${ch}.raw
```

Comment: `echo -n '\x40\x50\x60' | convert -size 1x1 -depth 8 rgb:- -channel R -separate -depth 8 gray:- | od -An -tx1` gives me `0xd` instead of `0x40`.

Comment: Try using `printf` instead of `echo`, that works for me.

Comment: The `echo -n '\x40\x50\x60'` does output the three bytes 0x40, 0x50 and 0x60 in my shell (`zsh`), but still, convert outputs one 0xd byte. I've just tested with the latest version released three days ago. Does it output 0x40 for you? Note that when converting _to_ `rgb:-` instead of `gray:-`, I do see `0x40 0x40 0x40` as expected.

Comment: It works if I add `-set colorspace RGB` (or `-set colorspace Gray` for that matters) and change `-channel R -separate` to `-fx r`.

Comment: 6.2.2 and 6.3.2 both work as expected, let me build 6.8.3-3 ...

Comment: @StephaneChazelas OK, it works as expected right up to 6.7.6-10, and breaks in 6.7.7-10, the `Changelog` indicates several colourspace changes in 6.7.7-*. Adding just `-set colorspace RGB` fixes this and works as expected in all 6.2.x-6.8x versions I have to hand. I've updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I need `printf 123 | convert -set colorspace rgb -colorspace srgb -size 1x1 -depth 8 rgb:- -channel R -separate gray:-`, that is `-colorspace srgb` in addition to `-set colorspace rgb` and it to be _before_ `-separate` for it to work with both 6.8.3-3 and 6.7.7-10. With `-fx r`, the `-colorspace` is not necessary. That smells like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

With ksh93, you can do:

```
command /opt/ast/bin/cut -r3 -Nb1 < file > red
command /opt/ast/bin/cut -r3 -Nb2 < file > green
command /opt/ast/bin/cut -r3 -Nb3 < file > blue
```

(yes, I know, there's no `/opt/ast/bin/cut` on your system, but chances are `ksh93` still has a builtin for it).

With `perl`:

```
perl -F -ane '
  BEGIN{
    $/=\3;
    map {open $f[$n++], ">", $_} qw{red green blue}
  }
  for $i (0..2) {print {$f[$i]} $F[$i]}'
```

With only standard Unix tools, you can do:

```
od -vAn -tu1 < file |
  tr -cs 0-9 '[\n*]' |
  grep . |
  paste - - - |
  awk '{printf "%c", $1 > "red"
        printf "%c", $2 > "green"
        printf "%c", $3 > "blue"}'
```

Those would split a `123123123123` "file" into a `1111` "red", `2222` "green" and `3333` "blue". If instead you want a "red" file that has `100100100100`, that is still a RGB file but where the other colours have been suppressed, you'd need to adapt the code above to output the extra NUL bytes for the other colours, or you could use an image manipulation utility like ImageMagick `convert`:

```
size=$(wc -c < file)
convert -size "1x$size" -channel GB -fx 0 rgb:- rgb:- < file > red
# ...and so on for green and blue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do channel separation using MATLAB. 
Read this: 
http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/03/08/tips-for-reading-a-camera-raw-file-into-matlab/
this shows how to read RAW data. Separating channels in MATLAB is easy, like sampling some elements in matrix.